# Append text file with command output, but replace the words that already exist (don't add the same text twice)

Tags: shell, text-processing, deduplication

I am appending a command output to a text file. But if I do it again it will have the same text twice in the text file. Is there a way with for example sed that if a word already exist don't add a new word, but just replace the old one?

What I am doing is appending the output of a ls command to a text file. So sometimes there are new files that have to be added to the text file, but then the files that were already there are now twice in the text file if you append again the ls output.

I hope you understand what i mean.

I am using AWS linux AMI

Edit:

I used

```
ls client_certs/ >> message.txt
```

I didn't use the `sed` command yet. If I do that `ls` command twice then I get double names for example:

- After first `ls client_certs/ >> message.txt`:

  ```
  1. 2. 3.
  ```
- After second `ls client_certs/ >> messages.txt`:

  ```
  1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3
  ```

What I want is:

- If I do the first time `ls client_certs/ >> message.txt`:

  ```
  1. 2. 3.
  ```
- If i do the second time `ls client_certs/ >> message.txt` :

  ```
  1. 2. 3.
  ```
- If there is a new file in `client_certs/` (for example `4.`) and I want to do `ls client_certs/ >> message.txt` it should show like this:

  ```
  1. 2. 3. 4.
  ```

Comment: Hi, please provide us some input and expected output examples, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please, edit your question to add these details

Comment: Why don't you use `>` instead of `>>`? Do you also want to keep in the record files that were deleted or moved away?

Comment: No if a file is removed in client_certs then I also want it gone in the text file

Comment: Then why are you *appending* (`>>`) as opposed to overwriting (`>`)? What is the information originally present in `message.txt` that you want be preserved.

Comment: In the message.txt do I have the names of the files in Client_certs. Sometimes I remove a file so then I also want it removed in message.txt the same with if I add a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
touch message.txt # the file must exist even if it is empty
ls client_certs | grep -vxFf message.txt >>message.txt
```

- `-xF` checks for whole literal (no regex) lines
- `-f message.txt` checks all lines in the file `message.txt`
- `-v` inverts the matches i.e. instead of printing everything in the file it prints everything which is not in the file

### delete old entries

The most simple solution is counting the entries in the directory and the file. If the numbers differ then delete and recreate the file:

```
touch message.txt # the file must exist even if it is empty
ls client_certs | grep -vxFf message.txt >>message.txt
# update the file, then compare
# save some time by trusting mtime
if [ client_certs -nt message.txt ] && [ $(wc -l message.txt) -ne $(ls -U client_certs | wc -l) ]; then
    : >message.txt # set file size to 0
    ls client_certs | grep -vxFf message.txt >>message.txt
fi
```

Of course, the question arises why the file should not just be deleted and recreated every time.

Comment: Would you mind adding an explanation on how this performs the desired task (your answer popped up in my "Low quality post" review queue, which I find somewhat sad ... ;) )

Comment: @AdminBee Wouldn't that be a feature if the answers of "trusted users" got whitelisted...

Comment: Yeah, that' true ;)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. This helped me alot, is there also a way for example if a file got deleted out of the client_certs file that it also can be deleted out of the text file?

I changed the command a little bit because I only want files with .ovpn extension in the text file: ls client_certs | grep '.ovpn' | grep -vxFf message.txt >>message.txt

I hope there is a way that if a file gets deleted out of client_certs it will also be deleted out of the text file. Again thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Danny What do you mean by "deleted"? It would be the easiest solution to just recreate the file after a mismatch has been detected.

Comment: @Hauke Laging The text in the text file I'm sending to my mail. I am doing this with sendmail and making it automatic with crontab, so I dont wan't to manualy recreate a file again.

Comment: @Danny I have edited my answer accordingly.